# Why my emails being block by yahoo and hotmail?

Tags: windows-server-2003, mysql, php, email, block

I received a lot of complaints from my users, they say that they can't find the activation email. I didn't do any blast emails or send spam emails. But I do send over 1000 emails daily, that's because of the signup. That means, in my registration process, I will send an activation email to the user to activate their account, and I think this is quite a standard method.

I tested my company email and gmail accounts, it works fine, only hotmail and yahoo emails, they just could not receive any emails from our website, not even in the junk/spam box.

Can anyone help me on this?

My server: Windows Server 2003, IIS6

Programming language & database: php and mysql

Answer (score 4):

Your email server may be on a blacklist, might not have a proper reverse lookup record, if you're on DSL it could look bad if it's too close to dynamic ranges (even if you have a static IP on "business class DSL") and a number of other things. Check the free tools on MXToolbox.com to see if any of those apply to you. You may want to consider creating an [SPF record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) for your domain as well. That can count in your favor in a Spam Confidence Level weighting algorithm. However, nothing can help you if you're on a blacklist. Get that checked out first.

**EDIT:**
In addition:

1. Check a more thorough DNSBL like http://www.dnsbl.info/
2. Read this article about spam, newsletter emails and major email providers: http://ask-leo.com/why_is_my_mail_to_hotmail_or_aol_yahoo_etc_subscribers_not_being_delivered.html
3. Take it up with the postmaster system at the problematic domains. I.e. http://postmaster.hotmail.com/

Comment: I checked. My domain is not on the blacklist. What should I do next???

Comment: As @nonapetide said, check the tools on MXToolbox.com.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend signing up for a free account on [SenderScore.org](https://www.senderscore.org/).  They have some very useful tools for diagnosing why your mails might be being rejected.