# My system generated emails[from php script] are going to spam folder in yahoo and hotmail

Tags: email, email-server, spam

We have an application running on biggerrole.com domain. We have hosted it on Hostgator VPS.
The application sends transactional emails to our registered users.
Currently the emails go to spam folder for yahoo/hotmail users [ google users get it in inbox]
I have set up SPF and domain keys.

Here is the headers for Yahoo..

```
From admin@biggerrole.com Fri Apr  8 10:18:30 2011
X-Apparently-To: piplayan@yahoo.com via 98.138.88.135; Fri, 08 Apr 2011 03:18:31 -0700
Return-Path: <admin@biggerrole.com>
X-YahooFilteredBulk: 174.122.51.197
Received-SPF: pass (mta140.mail.sp2.yahoo.com: domain of admin@biggerrole.com designates 174.122.51.197 as permitted sender)
X-YMailISG: dnBjapEcZAr94Z9Ovuwwtj_hhrCu9qv5Mf_A5UxIKsF3TbZh
 AKN4vekfWEmGa3Bygg9E89va3xgJ1GcDxcB5I7uzKvTO0rFkdoYOBBTDP6Ks
 KxktHdCQHSFsNJD.dp3ItrMLw3.BEeK1wwvHV_QZAldvO3yxcTqyrQRCCe14
 1eHlvC0o2fkuW2i9s__Y.O2DXf9sjCs1mtcPsIaQUi.WnNQazqWy5O6NnUwO
 iT2juogJG4BLjC6Wb_FgzMf._XMEKtFjO5QApiKniiSl4crgP1XB3_UTLzwI
 5CH4o7u4KY2BoJcPrXW9Yk_5l_JeIdDmA0Puvnhn4lGuk60CSO2gfCSvgYOO
 mGWiv.n0.aUiO6Yo.kfwreVK9YdynG8jveahIeOR8z3iQYGapuJfi0MX20GC
 oLa7zCSzCVu2jjNRFShtosEYzETVzPqoAqCwH2TwMVm1V92mzZHtTb.0jQou
 0kh1iLTnIySvLnnUbTmkJEZj8.xjlNVKgJQCnkl.bO0VcD9s9OExgKJS5I8q
 KxjmmKTl3DDm9Y_S9eqRuJEdc1OvMfaEUhAUveCp0O2K2Bcs4DY4adipx71Q
 lk5h5Gl6UDw6_YffabldYeFgAmEBNWN2hPf7AlsutoDfdwpuW07lip2HFz4a
 b9eUmBmT.GnxHxMKXQ1a07rVQdykYKepMo8FAKJg507uhkctaRXGf4NQK_5B
 4ZxNmQMzWfoxLLZk7JK0u4A5BIOobu1d9ABtwCjWzpiR_UUotzNm04XroHvN
 CwmkoBWtdXsL97yejLV3QJUZpzZep9BI9a8tvaAXsFynR7PrPPUcgfCLdLhr
 fiHbyNb.QCCO0Cut5SjFO5LCUcgU8z3XQXB4HIlnjSXOkhFJvcWUT3t20DYk
 rsIMyuipUndfD5AMeTv__PN3lDAhJBOKkpvNHVt5_h0J.wkWf3O.ZrTsDKjw
 epB5754uwoL7wQN1N3MzqRLNZ7pXt.OlDOHSjly4tchgreHDiMjGdIcygeAR
 n9TxYDEjM_RpC6T9TeDkdnYAA0qF7z_UHfVjtJzwMFyBXgl7WW.I4ghTAh1G
 L7eUG3ZDMx16HOvztdsHtm4v0Z4uevCM5jZanLPr8JVAwn6ICS4bqt_qPY7E
 SnfifBtlJClx21DO.qAJzygqFpZu40GpKvYr8rWl6NFEpXgAQDOaWGMyN7C5
 5ndri7Izv7o-
X-Originating-IP: [174.122.51.197]
Authentication-Results: mta140.mail.sp2.yahoo.com  from=biggerrole.com; domainkeys=pass (ok);  from=biggerrole.com; dkim=neutral (no sig)
Received: from 127.0.0.1  (EHLO big.biggerrole.com) (174.122.51.197)
  by mta140.mail.sp2.yahoo.com with SMTP; Fri, 08 Apr 2011 03:18:31 -0700
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; c=nofws; s=default; d=biggerrole.com;
    h=Received:To:Subject:X-PHP-Script:From:Reply-To:Message-Id:Date;
    b=zK9aPu0E9dTIpGxFouEL3o9pWnDwIpDZo+td+J5mHr3f4HMQk8ImTJjCi/Laabr1CZ0xmxY+juyztsNKmIE//K5qil+WYaL0APEKd5lp0PptMmO7MjEXscdLT0OPhtR9;
Received: from piplayan by big.biggerrole.com with local (Exim 4.69)
    (envelope-from <admin@biggerrole.com>)
    id 1Q88lq-0003UK-6Z
    for piplayan@yahoo.com; Fri, 08 Apr 2011 05:18:30 -0500
To: piplayan@yahoo.com
Subject: This is a programmatic email
X-PHP-Script: www.biggerrole.com/test_pip1.php for 209.95.240.41
From: admin@biggerrole.com
Reply-To: piplayan@gmail.com
Message-Id: <E1Q88lq-0003UK-6Z@big.biggerrole.com>
Date: Fri, 08 Apr 2011 05:18:30 -0500
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - big.biggerrole.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - yahoo.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [500 500] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - biggerrole.com
Content-Length: 29
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [All my emails to Yahoo!, Hotmail and AOL are going to Spam, though I've implemented every validation method (works for Gmail though)](http://serverfault.com/questions/106598/all-my-emails-to-yahoo-hotmail-and-aol-are-going-to-spam-though-ive-implement)

Answer (score 1):

Your server appear to fail rDNS validation.

```
$ host big.biggerrole.com
big.biggerrole.com has address 174.122.51.197
big.biggerrole.com mail is handled by 0 big.biggerrole.com.
$ host 174.122.51.197
197.51.122.174.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer c5.33.7aae.static.theplanet.com.
```

See my rant on [Running an Email Server](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/running-an-email-server/) for more things to check.  You also appear to have an excess number of MX records for your domain.

Answer (score 0):

change dkim record `DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; c=nofws;` to `a=rsa` this should help. [Here](https://serverfault.com/q/255181/43316) is similar question. ... hmmm  youve got

> with local (Exim 4.69)

there was some patch withtin 4.70 or 4.71 version. cant remembere what excactly, but something with dkim or domainkeys.